# RegularExpression get strings between new lines

Tags: regex, string

I want to taking every string who is located on a new line with Regular Expression

```
string someStr = "first
second
third
"
```

example:

```
string str1 = "first";
string str2 = "second";
string str3 = "third";
```

Comment: See regex tag description, there is a flavor/context missing.

Comment: thanks for all , but I mean:
`string someStr = "first
second
third
"`
pseudo-code
`str1 = someStr.RegExpr () // str1 contains only first line`

Answer (score 2):

Just split it with "\n";

```
someStr.split("\n")
```

And you can filter the empty strings if you'd like

Or if you *really* want regex, do `/^.*$/` with multiline flag

```
List<String> listOfLines = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("first\nsecond\nthird\n");
while (matcher.find()) {
   listOfLines.add(matcher.group());
}
```

Then you have;

```
listOfLines.get(0) = first
listOfLines.get(1) = second
listOfLines.get(2) = third
```

Comment: first
second
third  this data is just for example not worked everywhere

Comment: @Howto can you give an example that is breaking it?

Comment: @Howto are you going to resolve this question? I'd like to help more if my answer was not OK

Answer (score 2):

Or if you just want the first word of each line;

`^(\w+).*$` with multi-line flag.
Regex101 has a nice regex testing tool: https://regex101.com/r/JF3cKR/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following *regex* :

```
(\w+)(?=\n|"|$)
```

see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bDMivZ/5)

Comment: @bureaquete anything else? :P